# Unity3D Shooter: Using tags to switch level after killing all enemies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, 2d-games

I am new to Unity and was trying, after some suggestions, to use tags to know the number of enemies i have in each level and move to the next scene right after eliminating all enemies. This is the script i use on enemy gameobjects. I've also tagged each of them with the "enemy" tag in unity inspector but it still doesn't work when i run the game. After killing all the enemies, it didn´t change to next scene (Success!).  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Any other suggestions?
Thanks a lot for the help.

**Enemies Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; 

public class BadguyScript : MonoBehaviour
{

  public GameObject[] enemies;

  public int maxHealth;
  public int curHealth;
  private Animator myAnimator;
  private bool isDead;
  [SerializeField]
  private float DespawnTime = 2.5f;
  [SerializeField]
  private string DeathAnimHash = "isDead"; 

  void Start()
  {
      myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
      myAnimator.enabled =true;
      myAnimator.SetBool (DeathAnimHash ,isDead);


      maxHealth = 1;
      curHealth = maxHealth;



  }
  void Update()
  {
      if (curHealth < 1)
      {
          isDead = true;
          myAnimator.SetBool (DeathAnimHash ,isDead);
          Destroy(gameObject,DespawnTime);
      }
      enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy"); // Checks if enemies are available with tag "Enemy". 
      if (enemies.Length == 0)
      {
          SceneManager.LoadScene("SucessScene"); // Load the scene with name "SucessScene"
      }
  }
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
  {
      if (isDead)
         return;
      if (col.tag == "bullet")
      {
          curHealth -= 1;
          Destroy(col.gameObject);
      }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a script holder gameobject for this and put a GameManager script inside it. And inside GameManager.cs which should be a singleton class you can have a property like this:

```
int _enemyNumber;

public int EnemyNumber{
    get{
        return _enemyNumber;
    }
    set{
        _enemyNumber = value;
    }
}
```

And when you need to change these values, use some functions you will create inside this game controller such as:

```
public void DecreaseEnemyCount(){
    //do the logic here
}

public void SetEnemyCount(){
    //do the logic here
}
```

Also you can find information about creating a singleton class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447336/best-way-to-implement-unity-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

You create a list with all enemies, its a good practice, cause you'll gain performance. But you're verifing if enemies.Lenght == 0, what will never occur, because before you are adding the gameObject in the list `enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");`

In the start method, you can search for all enemies and add then in your array, and in the update or onTriggerEnter you remove it from your array and validate the array lenght. I think it'll be more easy.

Comment: he can initialize the list every time he enters in the level, and remove the enemies from the list after kill them, so he can check if the list.count == 0 and change of level.

he can put the script to remove the enemy from list in the enemy, so you don't need to iterate through all enemies checking if they are alive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the script to a new gameManager script attached to an empty game object cause now once all enemies are killed the script will not be in work but if added to an empty gameobject it will be working always.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).