# How to use singleton pattern in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, unity-game-engine, singleton

For school, I am making a little game. It is a sort of Mario clone. But I am struggling with the singleton pattern. I want to make a GameController to use in all the scenes. But I am not really experienced with that.

This is my GameController, it is used for a pause menu while in-game. When I start at the menu there is no Panel, but when playing a lvl there is a Panel(the pause menu). But when starting on the main menu and going to the first lvl it won't find the Panel. It says:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I thought that with `GameObject.Find("Panel")` i could find the panel and use it.

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
public static GameController Instance { get; private set; }


public bool GameIsPaused = false;
public GameObject Panel;
private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "MainMenu" || SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "LevelMenu")
    {
        Panel = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Panel = GameObject.Find("Panel");
        Panel.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if(!(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "MainMenu" || SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "LevelMenu")) {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else if (!GameIsPaused)
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286996/unity-singleton-pattern)

Comment: Or this? [Best way to implement Unity Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447336/best-way-to-implement-unity-singleton) .. However: Does `Panel` exist in the scene and is active?

Comment: You know btw that due to `DontDestroyOnload` the `Start` is never called again .. you probably rather want to listen to [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)

Comment: in the first scene in doesn't exist, but when I am switching to the second scene it does exist. but it won't find it, even when I put `GameObject.Find("Panel")` in the update method.